# Как изучить yii2?

Tags: php, yii2

друзья. Пол года назад решил зайти в веб, начал учить html/css и php. Выучил базовые вещи, даже сделал пару простеньких сайтиков. Увлёкся ВП ( понравилась простота функций и лояльность к разработке, в отличие от битрикса, там всё на ладони ).

К HTML сразу же начал учить bootstrap (признаться, учить там нечего, потому что всегда можно подсматривать в шпаргалку) и удивился, насколько фреймворк может облегчить жизнь.

Так как заниматься хочу бэком, начал гуглить ПХП фреймворки. Наткнулся на yii2 и Laravel, выбрал первый.

Начал искать в ютьюбе и рунете обучение, но нечего годного не нашёл. Посему, друзья, подскажите пожалуйста: а как вы учили данный фреймворк? Я скачал, покопался - блин, так интересно! Кажется, из-за того что я рано начал копаться в популярных СМСках, мне система контроллеров показалась знакомой, как лицо прохожего, которого ты "будто где-то когда-то встречал".

Если у кого есть книги, ресурсы, давайте! Буду изучать. Так, в изучении ПХП меня выручила книга "PHP 7 в подлиннике". Может, есть похожая подача для чайников и с yii?

Comment: По yii2 есть хорошая книга автора Марк Сафронов. Может быть она уже устаревает, но там есть чего полезного почитать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все хотят фреймворк) В ООП хорошо разбираешься? можешь MVC написать? Или свой велосипед). Вот для начала изучи "PHP Объекты шаблоны методы программирования". А так вот тебе учи https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/ru . Найди курсы их полно, смотри и учи.. а вообще больше практики.. пиши все что можно, от обычного перебора массива, до полноценного проекта.. со всеми плюшками... вот тут есть хорошие уроки webformyself, да много у кого.. ищи все в твоих руках)